# How to remove the section title and the section counter?

Tags: sectioning

From [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129978/how-to-remove-section-subsection-titles), I have the `fakesection`, like this

```
\newcommand{\fakesection}[1]{%
  \par\refstepcounter{section}% Increase section counter
  \sectionmark{#1}% Add section mark (header)
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}% Add section to ToC
  % Add more content here, if needed.
}
```

which servers the purpose of not having the `section tile`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\fakesection}[1]{%
  \par\refstepcounter{section}% Increase section counter
  %\sectionmark{#1}% Add section mark (header)
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}% Add section to ToC
  % Add more content here, if needed.
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{ Basic }
\fakesection{My section 08}
\fakesection{My section 09}
\fakesection{My section 10}
\fakesection{My section 11}

\part{ Intermediate }
\fakesection{My section 08}
\fakesection{My section 09}
\fakesection{My section 10}
\fakesection{My section 11}

\part{ Advanced }
\fakesection{My section 08}
\fakesection{My section 09}
\fakesection{My section 10}
\fakesection{My section 11}

\end{document}
```

How can I remove the section counters in the `toc` too? (keeping the title)

[image]
That is, the table of contents page should look like this, without the 1,2,3,4,etc...

Thanks.

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal example others can copy and work from. Btw what do you think the `\protect\numberline{....} `, play with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @daleif in the comment,

```
\newcommand{\fakesection}[1]{%
  \par\refstepcounter{section}% Increase section counter
  %\sectionmark{#1}% Add section mark (header)
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ #1}% Add section to ToC
  % Add more content here, if needed.
}
```

worked like a charm.

Comment: Remember to remove the space in from of `#1`, also, you probably don't need the `\refstepcounter `

Comment: @daleif Tried it. I do need it, as I want the hyper link to work in the bookmarks. Removing it would result them all being linked to the first `section`. So the whole document only has one section.

Comment: One word: `\phantomsection `, provides the necessary anchor