# Include `section` headers with `xcomment`

Tags: external-files

I use the package [`xcomment`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcomment) to make a stripped down version of `mynotes.tex`, including only theorems, definitions, etc. E.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcomment}
\usepackage{docmute}
% Other necessary packages
\xcomment{definition,notation,theorem,proposition,lemma,corollary}

\begin{document}
\input{mynotes.tex}
\end{document}
```

It would be helpful to also include `section` headings. The problem is that `\section{...}` is not an environment like `\begin{...} \end{...}`, so it will be ignored by `xcomment`.

Is there a way to include them? Or should I look at other packages like [`comment`](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment) (the problem is, that I don't know if `comment` can *only* include the above mentioned environments and section headers)?

Comment: What do you want to do? Wouldn't removing all sections make the resulting file empty?

Comment: [sectioning - How to remove Section, SubSection titles? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129978/how-to-remove-section-subsection-titles) ?

Comment: @user202729 No, I want it the other way around. All `\section` commands should be *included* in the resulting file, as well as my desired theorem environments.

Comment: What does it mean? Include only the section title and not the content inside the section?

Comment: @user202729 Exactly, only the bold face `...` in `\section{...}` (and also some specified environments). But no outside text, no toc, no `examples` and `remarks` environments, etc.

Comment: Why not just read the table of content then?

Comment: The idea is to have a kind of summary for study purposes.